# Menu em duas colunas CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap

Tenho uma estrutura bootstrap de CSS. 
Este menu ele fica desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu gostaria de dividir em duas colunas, como eu poderia fazer?
Não houve nenhuma alteração de estrutura do menu bootstrap normal.

Segue o código do menu:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Produtos<span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
        <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
</li> 

#mu-menu .navbar-default .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 0px;
}
#mu-menu .navbar-default .navbar-nav li .dropdown-menu {
    border-top: 2px solid #ED3237;
}
.navbar-nav > li > .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 0;
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
}

.navbar-nav > li {
    float: left;
}
.nav > li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você pode usar o que está sendo ensinado em [Bootstrap Multi-column Dropdown Menu](http://alijafarian.com/bootstrap-multi-column-dropdown-menu/).

Basicamente ele cria algumas classes css (`.multi-column` para a `ul` e as `.columns-2` e `.columns-3` para especificar o número correto de colunas, além das classes relacionadas a `.multi-column-dropdown` para estilo).

```
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 200px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-2 {
    min-width: 400px;
}
.dropdown-menu.columns-3 {
    min-width: 600px;
}
.dropdown-menu li a {
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
.multi-column-dropdown {
    list-style: none;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    color: #333;
    white-space: normal;
}
.multi-column-dropdown li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #262626;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .dropdown-menu.multi-column {
        min-width: 240px !important;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
}
```

E o uso fica da seguinte forma (código copiado da fonte, citada acima):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-header-->

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">One Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Two Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-2">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here that's extra long so we can see how it looks</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Three Column <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu multi-column columns-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <ul class="multi-column-dropdown">
                                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!--/.navbar-collapse-->
</nav>
<!--/.navbar-->
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Justamente isso mesmo, deu certinho, muito obrigado!

Comment: Farei isto, @renan. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

André, deixo aqui uma abordagem boa quando a questão é dropdown com vários itens, você pode colocar um scroll, este formato é quase zero configuração apenas um css a mais e funciona tanto mobile quanto desktop.

**Exemplo:**

```css
.scrollable-menu {
  height: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Scrollable Menu <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu scrollable-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 7</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 8</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 9</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 10</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```